# Multiple user access through single VPN connection

Tags: networking, virtualization, vpn, permissions, virtual-machines

We currently have to use proprietary VPN software to connect through to one of our clients and due to the fact that it's legacy software they're not willing to create extra user accounts to allow us to connect more than one user at a time.

This is an issue given the number of projects we do for the client as well as scheduling in the long-term.

**Extra Info:**

1. The VPN software requires Windows XP to run
2. Once connected, the VPN blocks all access to the internet and any local networks. It seems to be direct into the VPN.
3. We'd like to have multiple instances where a developer [A] can just patch into a VPN connection whilst another developer [B] is still working, without seeing the connected developers [B] work-in-progress.

**TL;DR**

*Is it possible to have multiple users work through a single (proprietary) VPN connection without them treading on each others feet?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Not if the VPN client makes itself the default route for all traffic and defends its position by stopping you setting up alternative routing after successful connection (which it probably does).

On the off-chance that it doesn't defend its position as the only route for network traffic you can try editing the routing table yourself, but I'm not all that familiar with this under Windows (I'm more a Linux man in that area) but perhaps someone else might be able to help. If you can reset the routing table such that the machine running the VPN client can see, and respond to, your local LAN you can then try configure ICS, or some other form of NAT, to "share" the connection.

This might be a case where you have no choice but to simply explain to that client the if they don't give a little regarding the VPN access, you will have to lengthen any project time estimates to account for not being able to have two+ people work concurrently on the project at times which it would be a great help, or you will have to charge extra to cover overtime if developers have to work late to finish project work because they were waiting for the VPN connection to become free earlier. Of course if they are a significant client and you have direct competitors they might consider using this could be a dangerous position to take, but that is a business decision rather than a technical one.